# Transforming Towers Of Hanoi Movement Sequence To Configuration Sequence

Tags: haskell, towers-of-hanoi

As part of some "self imposed homework" on Haskell study, I did the classic solution of the Towers of Hanoi:

```
doHanoi :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int)]
doHanoi 0 _ _ = []
doHanoi n from to = first ++ [(from, to)] ++ last 
    where
        using = 3 - from - to;
        first = doHanoi (n - 1) from using; 
        last = doHanoi (n - 1) using to
```

(where the meaning of `doHanoi n from to using` get the asequence of movements assuming the disks `0.. n - 1` are at peg `from`, and we need to move them to peg `to`.)

This gives the sequence of movements, e.g.,

```
>>> doHanoi 3 0 2
[(0,2),(0,1),(2,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(0,2)]
```

I then wanted to see if I could transform the output into the set of configurations (i.e., initially, all rings are on the left peg, then there are intermediate configurations, finally all rings are on the right peg). I could do this by writing a `changeConfig` function

```
changeConfig :: [[Int]] -> (Int, Int) -> [[Int]]
changeConfig [e0:e0s, e1s, e2s] (0, 1) = [e0s, e0:e1s, e2s]
changeConfig [e0:e0s, e1s, e2s] (0, 2) = [e0s, e1s, e0:e2s]
changeConfig [e0s, e1:e1s, e2s] (1, 0) = [e1:e0s, e1s, e2s]
changeConfig [e0s, e1:e1s, e2s] (1, 2) = [e0s, e1s, e1:e2s]
changeConfig [e0s, e1s, e2:e2s] (2, 0) = [e2:e0s, e1s, e2s]
changeConfig [e0s, e1s, e2:e2s] (2, 1) = [e0s, e2:e1s, e2s]
```

then using [`scanl`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=scanl):

```
>>> scanl changeConfig [[0.. 2], [], []] (doHanoi 3 0 2 1)
[[[0,1,2],[],[]],[[1,2],[],[0]],[[2],[1],[0]],[[2],[0,1],[]],[[],[0,1],[2]],[[0],[1],[2]],[[0],[],[1,2]],[[],[],[0,1,2]]]
```

While this works, I think I'm missing something in `changeConfig`: this is just an exhaustive enumeration of all configurations, in a setting that has some form of cyclic symmetry, that happened to work because there are three pegs, and would not scale well (in terms of LOC). What is the "Haskellic" way to write it?

Comment: Could you please document your function? What exactly is `n`? What exactly is `using`? And where did you find this algorithm?

Comment: @dfeuer Sorry for that - I added an explanation. Please LMK if anything else is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `using` doesn't have to be specified as an argument; it is completely specified by `3 - (from + to)`.

Comment: @chepner Many thanks. That does indeed simplify the code in the first part of the question (now corrected/updated). The focus of the question is on the second part, though, that uses of the output from the first part to build the configurations.

Comment: Well, you could define functions `popNth :: Int -> [[x]] -> (x, [[x]])` and `pushNth :: Int -> x -> [[x]] -> [[x]]` and define `changeConfig` in terms of that right?

Comment: @jberryman Good idea, thanks! It's what I'll do.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to kind help by chepner and jberryman, here's what I came up with.

The function finding the movements is unchanged:

```
doHanoi :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int)]
doHanoi 0 _ _ = []
doHanoi n from to = first ++ [(from, to)] ++ last 
    where
        using = 3 - from - to;
        first = doHanoi (n - 1) from using; 
        last = doHanoi (n - 1) using to
```

Now an auxiliary function, `changePeg es i from to new_e` returns the output to peg `i` assuming it contained elements `es`, its index was `i`, the movement was from `from` to `to`, and of element `new_e`.

```
changePeg :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
changePeg es i from to new_e
    | i == from = tail es
    | i == to = new_e: es
    | otherwise = es
```

Using this, `changeConfig` becomes

```
changeConfig :: [[Int]] -> (Int, Int) -> [[Int]]
changeConfig es (from, to) = new_es where
    new_e = head $ es !! from;
    new_es = [changePeg (es !! i) i from to new_e | i <- [0.. 2]]
```

As before, the solution can be found with

```
>>> scanl changeConfig [[0.. 2], [], []] (doHanoi 3 0 2)
[[[0,1,2],[],[]],[[1,2],[],[0]],[[2],[1],[0]],[[2],[0,1],[]],[[],[0,1],[2]],[[0],[1],[2]],[[0],[],[1,2]],[[],[],[0,1,2]]]
```